# passing two 2-d arrays into a function for comparison

Tags: c, arrays, comparison, compare

I have been trying to pass two arrays into a function so that I can compare them but I am having trouble with the syntax of how to pass the arrays and begin to compare the rows.  I am getting errors such as incompatible pointer types pass to type const char????  here is the code I have so far...im having trouble in the top sort function

//

```
#define MAXROWS    30
#define MAXCOLS   100 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char topsort( char, int, char, int);    

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //array for all of the word's in the file
    char list[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS], line[MAXCOLS], constraint[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
    FILE *list_sort;
    int listcols = 0, listrows = 0, concols = 0, conrows = 0;

    //open the sequential access file and make sure its found
    list_sort = fopen("/Volumes/JENN/cpma stuff/introcompsys/list sort.txt","r");
    if(list_sort == NULL){
        printf("can't open file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), list_sort) != NULL)
    {
        if(index(line, ',') == NULL){
            for(listcols =0; listcols< strlen(line)-1 ;++listcols)  {
                list[listrows][listcols] = line[listcols];
            }
            list[listrows][listcols] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", list[listrows]);  //print each row of the list to check
            ++listrows;
        }
        else{
            for(concols =0; concols< strlen(line)-1 ;++concols)  {
                constraint[conrows][concols] = line[concols];
            }
            constraint[conrows][concols] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", constraint[conrows]);  //print each row of the constraint to
            //check
            ++conrows;
        }

    }
}
char topsort( char s1[][MAXCOLS], int listrows, char s2[][MAXCOLS], int conrows){
char sorted[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];

while(the constraint array is not empty){     //pseudocode
    int second = char *strchr(s2, ‘,’+ 2);  
    for(int i = 0; i < listrows ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < conrows; j++){
            strcspn(s2[j][second], s1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the declaration of your function?

Comment: Add warnings/errors to question please.

Comment: Include all error messages including line numbers. Also sample input.

Comment: What exactly is your problem in `topsort`? That the syntax `strlen[][])` is wrong? Or that your `while` condition is never updated and will be either always true or always false? That `strcspn` calculates a length that you never store? That you try to call `topsort` before it is declared?

Comment: i know top sort has TONS of problems...i started learning C two days ago and need to write a program in it in a week so I'm just trying to find all the help I can get!  my only programming experience is 7 weeks in java ;/

Comment: @user3215644: SO probably isn't a good place for crash courses in C. And I have to say that you're not making life especially easy for those who are willing to help. You could start by explaining your assignment. From the code snippets I gather that you read two lists of strings. You check for commas. What is the exact format of the file? Your pseudocode for `topsort` looks as if you were stripping the constraints from the others string, but I'm not sure. Then you talk about sorting and comparing, but there's nothing of that sort. We might help you, but we won't read your mind.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple problems with topsort. It's not going to work.

This is a bad idea:

```
char s1[][MAXCOLS]
```

Either specify all the dimension sizes, or use char **.

This is wrong, for several reasons.

```
int length = strlen(s2[][]);
```

You don't give any array indexes, you're passing a char to a function that takes a char *, and you are using length in a while loop and never changing it.

```
strlen(&s1)
```

This is passing a char * * * to a function expecting a char *.

```
strcspn(s2[i], s1[i]);
```

passing two chars to a function that takes a char and a char *.  Plus you don't even see the result.

Comment: How is `char s1[][MAXCOLS]` a bad idea? In this case, where the argument (supposedly) passed from `main` has a signature `list[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS]`, `char **s1` is a worse idea, because the data is contiguous and not an array of pointers.

Comment: what do the * or ** mean when in front of a variable?  also the function is obviously not "functioning"....i do not know the syntax for comparing the values inside the rows of the array versus just pointing to them